# Javascript Firefox - cssRule object not returing id selector style in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

i have 3 blocks of style rule in my stylesheet.
1 ID selector
2 class selectors

After querying cssRules from CSSStyleSheet, it's returning only class selector related styles. How to get id related styles from external stylesheet?

Note: I am using firefox.

```
var style_rules = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
console.log(style_rules.length); //2

for(var i=0; i < style_rules.length; i++) {

console.log(style_rules[i].selectorText); 
 console.log(style_rules[i].style.cssText);
 }
```

CSS stylesheet:

```
//@import 'reset.css';

#content {
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:200px;
height:200px;
width:200px;
}

.red {
background-color:red;
}

.green{
color:yellow;
background-color:green;
}
```

Updated: if i remove commented @import it works fine for me. Seems to be bug.

Comment: Please post the URL to that external CSS file.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/u4v63/2

Comment: i am using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js.css" /> on localhost.

Comment: Updated: if i remove commented @import it works fine for me. Seems to be bug.

Comment: The `//` is invalid in CSS. To comment in CSS, use `/*` and `*/`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
//@import 'reset.css';
```

The `//` form is not valid in CSS. You have to use `/*` and `*/` to comment out CSS code.

```
/* @import 'reset.css'; */
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u4v63/5/